# Error DNS over HTTPS Setup "Unable to Find the DNS Parameter"

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq, dnsdist

I am having problems finding a guide that provides what I need to setup DoH on a self-hosted server. In the end, my final error is "Unable to find the DNS parameter" when using POWERDNS DNSDIST as my DoH server. DNSDIST is installed from ubuntu apt repository. My setup:
NGINX Reverse Proxy -> LXC container running Ubuntu Server 22.10 -> running Bind9 as local recursive DNS resolver and DNSDIST as the DoH capable server.
(My test machine is running dnscrypt-proxy, but the problem is way before this)

Unable to find the DNS parameter`

Guides that I followed with the same results: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/dns-over-https-doh-resolver-ubuntu-dnsdist , https://blog.apnic.net/2020/02/28/how-to-deploy-dot-and-doh-with-dnsdist/, https://www.bentasker.co.uk/posts/documentation/linux/407-building-and-running-your-own-dns-over-https-server.html

Well that is it. Please any help would be much appreciated.